# Centering hyperlink containing an image

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, positioning

I have run into a problem that seems rather dull but I can't seem to solve it. I have the following HTML which I **cannot** change:

```
<a href="#" class="aligncenter">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x150" alt="">
</a>
```

The width of the image is not known in advance. The CSS I initially used was

```
a {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
    padding: 2px;
    display: block;
}
img {
    display: block;
}
```

*Note* that I can't set `text-align: center` on the parent of `a`!

Sometimes the image is as large as the wrapper (in the fiddle below that's `body`) and then there's no problem. However, sometimes the image is smaller than the wrapping element in which case there'll be white space that fills up the empty space. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4o9df9sd/1/).

A possible solution is positioning the link right-from-center with a `margin-left` (using percentual values from the parent) and then reprositioning it with `translate`(using percentual values of the element). [See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4o9df9sd/2/) *However, this can't be used in IE8.*

```
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Is there an easier/better solution that I am overlooking that should be able to handle this behaviour cross-browser? I am also interested in hearing ideas that are not restricted to IE8-compatibility. (For instance flex boxes, with which I am not experienced.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking...but centering the image is simple enough - http://jsfiddle.net/4o9df9sd/3/

Comment: If however, you want the link to shrink-wrap around the image then `inline-block` would seem to be what you are after - http://jsfiddle.net/4o9df9sd/5/ . `Text-align:center` on the parent then centers it.

Comment: @Paulie_D As I state in my post, I want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4o9df9sd/2/) where the link wraps around the image rather than the image floating in the link. But this fiddle does not work in IE8 because of transform. Also I feel that there should be an easier solution.

Comment: See my second comment.

Comment: @Paulie_D Should've mentioned that I can't set text-align on the parent of `a` which would mess up the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4o9df9sd/6/)**

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Edit: **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4o9df9sd/10/)**

So according to your requirement i changed like this:

css:

```
a img {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: As I state in my post, I want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4o9df9sd/2/) where the link wraps around the image rather than the image floating in the link. But this fiddle does not work in IE8 because of transform. Also I feel that there should be an easier solution.

Comment: Still not what I want. Look at the link in my previous comment. That's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the border to the `img` tag, set the `a` width to 100% and then set automatic margins on the img, the image should align in the middle.

```css
body {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  display: inline;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="aligncenter">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/240x150" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: The width of the image is not known in advance.

Comment: @BramVanroy I had a stupid moment and for some reason over complicated it all, see my amended answer and you should be all good :D

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The hyperlink still fills 100% width, and I need it to wrap around the image as per my fiddle.

Comment: As I said in my OP, I can't use text-align center ;)

Comment: Can you use javascript by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It would be easy to solve with JS by calculating the needed left margin. :)